# How to refresh a child view in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` showing some `TextView`s, the views are drawn so that **ONE** is marked as selected. The problem is that when the user interaction changes the selected item in my logic I want to update the views involved, namely *the view showing previous selected item* and *the view showing the current selected item*. (Of course in my real problem the child views in the grid are more complex as well as the update process which could involve some calculations, loading of resources, accessing databases, etc.)

Till now I'm using `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` or `GridView.invalidateViews` and both do the work but also updates **ALL** the visible child views of the `GridView` but what I want is to update just **TWO** views among them.

How can I do that? How to get just the two views for the updating process?

Note: I'm facing this problem with `ListView`s also but I think maybe it will have the same solution.

Example code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int selectedPos = 36;

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 100;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv;
            if(convertView==null) {
                tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            } else {
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            }
            Log.d("Updating -----", String.valueOf(position));
            if(position==selectedPos)
                tv.setText("Item ".toUpperCase() + String.valueOf(position));
            else
                tv.setText("Item " + String.valueOf(position));             
            return tv;
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedPos = position;
                //gv.invalidateViews();
                ((MyAdapter)gv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }    
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like (some kind of pseudo code):

```
updateThisViewAsNotSelected(selectedPos);
gv.redrawThisView(selectedPos);
selectedPos = position;
updateThisViewAsSelected(selectedPos);
gv.redrawThisView(selectedPos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recreating views all the time:**

What exactly is the problem of updating the views when `getView` is called? If you do nothing but change the text of a `TextView` I can see no problem.

If you are planning to do something more you need to change your view on `Adapter`s. See below.

**Long running operations and adapters**

You should never do any long running operations in the adapter itself. And not in getView at all.

You should begin thinking about `Adapter`s as... well adapters. They adapt the data you have to the current UI context.

So it's not the job of the adapter to fetch data from the database or anything like that. The adapter should be fed data and simply adapt it into views.

For feeding the adapter with data consider using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It performs operations away from the UI threat and and can update the adapter when it is done.

You can for example let the Adapter have a List of objects that represent each view. Then to update the adapter you just need to provide it a new list of changed objects and notify it that the data has changed.

Comment: Still the problem, I want just TWO views to be updated, not all, if there is no simple way of doing that I can live without it then. Obviate what I'm doing in the update process it was just an example. The point is why update all the visible views if I only care about TWO.

Comment: How do you know they are being updated? Can you see any difference in the views that are not changing text? If not then why do you care? Maybe Android is smart enough not to update the pixels on the screen if they are not changed.

Comment: First I need to update the view of the previously selected item and then the view of the newly selected item, I know the position of the items I just need the views or use something like  `GridView.recreateThisView(int)`

Comment: Okay. I cannot see why you would not let the adapter do the work for you? As I mentioned nothing long running is happening in getView, so it is not a performance issue. I cannot see what is wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse through the visible children of the list or grid view to achieve to that. For example, if you'd like to achieve that with a grid view:

```
for(int k = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); k <= gridView.getLastVisiblePosition(); k++) {
   View view = gridView.getChildAt(k);
   // you can update the view here
}
```

If you'd like to get a child from a specific position:

```
int firstVisiblePosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

for (int k = 0; k < gridView.getChildCount(); k++ ) {
    int current = firstVisiblePosition + k;

    if (current == updateThisPosition) {
        View child = gridView.getChildAt(i);

        // Update the view
        TextView anything = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.anything_text);
        anything.setText("updated!"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: What if the views I need to update are not visible? Besides, how I identify the two views needed? I'm looking for something like `GridView.getViewAtPosition(int)`

Comment: if it's not visible, it means it doesn't exist yet. Therefore you can update those in the getView method of your adapter. This is for the ones that are already created.